# How to structure big classes?

Tags: java, class

I am currently writing a Java API for communicating with a device. The original API for the device provided by the devices manufacturer is written in C and is basically just one big header file defining every struct, enum and function necessary for communicating with the device. A lot of these structs and functions are actually for changing device Settings or retrieving device Information.

Since im porting this API to Java i wanted to make the API more OO-ish and more easy to use for someone who has no actual knowledge about the device and its C API. My Goal is to have one class `Device` which has methods for connecting and retrieving data from the device.

Now i am wondering how i should incorporate all the Settings and Information in my class. If i basically do an OO-Port of the original API the class would get reeeaaally big and harder to use as a result. What i did for a start was putting all the Settings Information in its own class and making that class a member of my `Device` class. The `DeviceSettings` class will have a reference to its `Device` classes Connection object (Basically an object that handles the communication with the C API through JNI/JNA).

It now looks something like this:

```
class Device {
    private JNIDeviceConnection connection;

    private DeviceSettings settings;
    private DeviceInformation information;
    private SpecificDeviceSettingsA spSettingsA;
    ...

    public void connect();
    public void disconnect();
    public DataObject getData();

    public Device() {
        settings = new DeviceSettings(connection);
        ...
    }
}
```

Using the class would look like this:

```
Device dev = new Device();
dev.connect();
dev.getDeviceSettings().changeSettingA(newValue);
dev.getData();
dev.disconnect();
```

Do you think this is a good approach to this kind of problem? I feel like the class does too much, but i would rather have a class doing too much than having something like this:

```
Device dev = new Device()
dev.connect()
DeviceSettingsUtility.changeSettingsA(dev, newValue);
...
```

Am i missing an obvious better alternative?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of response are you expecting. it seems that you don't have any problem.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I am not sure if what i am doing (composing Utility classes into my main class) is good OO or not. I was hoping for a "As long as it fits your needs it doesn't matter", or "This will give you problems when you do XXX" answers.

Comment: As long as it fits your needs it doesn't matter :P And seriously now - extracting the code into classes and creating instances of these classes is much better approach that using static methods.

Comment: I guess i didn't accept an answer at that point in time as i was not satisfied with any of them. The whole project was for my university, as the students there learn Java in their first year and never really touch C/C++. As it is was approved to be [open sourced](https://github.com/FG-SE/iviewx-java), I can now say that it was about an eye tracking library. In the end a static monolith which manages the connection and some additional services that use said connection turned out to be the right design choice in my opinion.

Comment: By the way i completely agree with you, a static monolith is no good design choice in general. But in my case, the underlying technology was restricting me so much, that a static monolith made the whole API easier to use, while having no real downside. I then added some abstractions for concurrent use of the eyetracker on top of that, as that seemed to be the most critical point of the whole library. The whole thing basically cut down a recurring pattern in eyetracking from 200+ lines of boilerplate code to something around 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents: don't do that.

Don't put a single/static class monolith into java code, just to resemble some ancient C API. Because: that does add little to no value. And will become a maintenance nightmare immediately.

No serious java programmer will like to use your new "product"; and no serious C programmer will see the need to move to a new language if there is no real gain from it.

Long story short: don't waste your time "copying" what is already there. Instead, understand the requirements; and design a clean, easy to use, "state of the art" API that has the potential to attract people (and other maintainers that support you in the long run). Meaning: go full OO, provide reasonable abstractions, etc. ...

Answer (score 0):

If I had to structure this I would have done something like this below:

**Model:**

```
//With getter and setter and other details

Device : composed of {DeviceSettings, DeviceInformation}
DeviceSettings:
DeviceInformation:
```

**Manager/Service:**

```
ConnectionManager:
                |
                -getCnnection(Device device)
DeviceManager:
             |
             - connect(Device device)
             - disconnect(Device device)
             - changeSettings(Device device)
```

**Usage :**

```
DeviceManager.changeSettings(device, setting){
  //get the current setting and update
}
```